# UK standard visit visa rejected from India for my wife and 2 kids

Tags: uk, india, standard-visitor-visas

[image]
My wife and kids plan to visit London for a 3-week vacation was refused. I have attached the image with the rejection letter. I am in the UK on a business visa and returning back to India on April 20th. My plan was to bring them here on March 29th, have 3 weeks of vacation and return together. I lost 25k+ Rupees for the first attempt.

Everyone is suggesting me to apply again with additional documents. Let me list the documents below that I am planning to submit. Read the documents as if my wife is submitting it. On our first attempt I submitted documents until 11 and the remaining are the new ones added for the second attempt.

Do you recommend to reapply in the first place with the refusal comments they have given? Do you think the new documents are sufficient to prove the reasons of rejections? Do you recommend anything more than what I have listed below? I appreciate a quick response as I have very little time.

1. Application form of myself and kids.
2. Appointment confirmation of myself and kids.
3. Payment confirmation of myself and kids.
4. Passports for myself and kids.
5. Birth certificate of kids.
6. Marriage certificate.
7. Bank statements, both mine and my husband’s.
8. No objection letter from my husband’s office.
9. UK photographs.
10. My husband’s passport and visa copy.
11. ID proof/address proof for myself.
12. Cover letter from my husband’s office explaining the purpose of his visit to the UK and why his stay was extended.
13. Letter and receipt from kids' school explaining that we have taken admission for the next academic year.
14. Husband's confirmed return air ticket for April 20th.
15. Income tax statements of my husband.
16. Invitation letter from my husband for us.
17. Husband's medical insurance expiring on April 20th.
18. Husband's salary slips.

Does anyone know if the second attempt takes more time than the first one?. First we got the rejection letter in 5 working days...second one already crossed 9 working days. Just out of curiosity and tension am asking this question. If its getting delayed is good sign or a bad sign?

Comment: You should blank out the name and date of birth from the photo

Comment: And his account info, which could easily lead someone to find out where he's working. If the visa officer seems to suspect what it sounds like he/she does, OP may not want that info all over the internet. Change your account name OP!

Comment: @user16259 has it right.  Your proposed item 12, a description of your husband's activities in the UK, could get him in trouble if his activities are not allowed for a business visitor.  It would not be wise to submit that unless it has been cleared by a competent lawyer.

Comment: What are the grounds for refusal. Please re-attach your refusal paper with your personal details blanked out.

Comment: Done!. Please let me know your view on this.@TheLastWord

Comment: @AnishMathew, it might be helpful to state exactly which visa class you have.

Comment: @Conrad I am on a  Business visa.

Comment: @AnishMathew - I suspect you maybe have a [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa), for business purposes. If this is the case, it could be the reason that the refusal letter mentions that should not be working in the UK. This is in contrast to the [Work visa](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/work-visas).

Comment: @Conrad I am on a Standart visitor visa and not working. I am not earning anything in UK. I am here for business purposes only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the main refusal of the visa is that your spouse mentioned that he is on a business trip from 28th Oct 2017 to 20th Apr 2018. Looks too long. Might be visa officer suspect that your spouse trying to settle down in UK.

However, the points you mentioned above after 11, are useful. So, you should try again.

Best Luck !!!!!

Comment: Thanks Maqsood for the comment. Planning to submit the documents this thursday for which we got the appointment. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Did you see the latest documents I attached, Does that makes sense to you?. whats the sucess rate of reapplying visa after a refusal with such documents?

Answer (score 10):

You need an expert lawyer. The visa officer thinks you are working illegally in the UK. Your own visa could be at risk.

The reason is, I think, that you have spent a long time in the UK, which is usually incompatible with the permitted activities of a business visitor.  Business visits normally only allow you to make sales presentations or get briefed by customers, with main work to be done in your country of residence.

Comment: thanks for the response. I totally get your points. How much does a lawyer cost for such cases?. This is probably my last visit to UK as my knowledge transfer from the UK guys and Vice-versa will get completed. So I am not worried much about whether they will allow me to come back to UK again. My bank statement and Salary slips should explain them that I am not earning anything in UK. Will try for one last time with these additional documents and thats it. My confirmed return ticket for April 20th.

Comment: You misunderstand what it means to work illegally in the UK. Even if you are being paid by your company to your bank account, the things you are doing in the UK may be considered 'work' which is not permitted for business visitors. Or they may be permitted activities and you will be fine. The issue is more than just your visa: the UK client may be unable to invite visitors in future, or your firm may not be able to serve other UK clients.

Comment: so should I give it a try once more with the additional document 12-18 or just dont try?. what do you recommend?

Comment: If you are not going to hire a lawyer then you should review the permitted activities of a business visitor and try to judge if you are complying with your visa. If you believe you are complying then yes, apply again, with a very careful explanation to the visa office.

Comment: thanks. Attached is the covering letter from Bangalore office that I am submitting this time to explain what activities I am doing in UK. Please review and see if this looks good.

Comment: Also attached is the school fees paid receipt from the school for both the kids for the academic year 2018-19

Comment: I strongly advise you to remove your personal details like children's names from those attachments. And I am sorry but I am not qualified to give specific advice on the cover letter.

Comment: You don't seem to be understanding @user16259's point. A 'business visit' is not usually so long, and the ECO clearly believes you are in violation in terms of your visa. Even if you aren't being paid in the UK, your activities *may* constitute work. Given that you have put your real name here, which can be traced to you and your company, combined with multiple visa applications, it's very risky. Unless you are totally, 100% sure that your activities are permitted, and you can 100% prove that in the docs (have a lawyer prepare) I don't see why a 2nd application would change anything.

Comment: @AnishMathew I am actually quite surprised that your company did not educate you on what a business visa means before sending you to the UK. From your use of the term "knowledge transfer" and the name of your company, you seem to be from the IT industry, most likely working as an engineer, so your own ignorance of the visa you applied for is also strange, especially when this could have serious consequences for you and your employer. Your statement that you don't plan to come back to UK, so you don't care if they think you are working illegally is incredibly naive. (No offence meant.)

Comment: @MaskedMan Ofcourse I know. This is the 5th time I am visiting UK and all my visits lasted for 4-6 months. What I have is a 2 year long term business visa which allows me to stay upto a maximum of 6 months. I have provided enough doca to show that I am not working in UK nor I am making any money here. I am actually spending more and get it reimbursed by Indian company. As a business visitor I am allowed to conduct meetings, Conduct meetings, Undergo trainings and attend business conferences. We have hired 4 new guys here in UK and I am training them as part of knowledge transfer.

Comment: I am not doing anything as work or something not I am not permitted to do as business visitor. They didnt had any issue in giving me entry when they know that all my last 4 visits lasted for almost 5-6 months. They noticed it only when I applied for tourist visa for my family to come here.

Comment: To clarify, your company has offices of the same corporate group in the UK and that is where you are delivering training? That should be OK so you could reapply for your wife and make this very clear in the application.

Comment: @user16259 one clarification there. The company in India that I work is Antrix and the client who is in UK is Moxie. They use our Product and hence requires training which I am giving them, Ofcourse I do understand its a long time but my client took some time to recruit new employees and I need to do the onboard training for 2 months.I have clearly mentioned why my stay got extended.We have applied for the visa with all additional documents and waiting for the results. Have you ever heard such situation that led to rejection and later got approved?. I am very tensed.

Comment: I can't guess if you will be approved but each application is judged on its merits so it is possible. I'm unclear if Moxie and Antrix are part of the same corporate group, based on what you wrote. If not, you really do appear to be in breach of UK immigration rules. Have a look at sections 5 and 6 here https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules#visitors-appendix-3-permitted-activities-for-all-visitors